# docmd.applyfilter on navigation form in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is there anyway to apply a filter (without using SQL script), when using a navigation form?

When I do the docmd.applyfilter outside of the navigation form it works.
When I move the form to my navigation form it no longer works - I have looked at how I reference my form etc.

Code I have is

```
Dim BusinessTermLookup As String

BusinessTermLookup = Me!CmbSimilarMatch
Me.Filter = "[businessterm]like ' & BusinessTermlookup '"
Me.FilterOn = True
```

I tried to use docmd.applyfilter - but it gives an error

> The action or method is invalid because the form or report isn't bound to a table or query

Comment: The filter in navigation form should be applied to navigation form subform control, not to the form object you use as navigation form page. Each time when you click navigation button, it replaces form object in subform control dynamically. Please provide code example you use for applying the filter and comment, where is control name and object name

Comment: Hi
Code I have is
`Dim BusinessTermLookup As String

BusinessTermLookup = Me!CmbSimilarMatch

Me.Filter = "[businessterm]like ' & BusinessTermlookup '"
Me.FilterOn = True`

I tried to use docmd.applyfilter - but it gives an error `The action or method is invalid because the form or report isn't bound to a table or query`

Comment: Where did you use this code? Inside the form you use as navigation page?

Comment: And filter should be `"[businessterm] Like '*" & BusinessTermlookup & "*'"`

Comment: Code is inside the form inside the navigation form. But the error that you picked up solved the problem, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter text should be `"[businessterm] Like '*" & BusinessTermlookup & "*'"` and make sure that the filter in navigation form applied to navigation form subform control, not to the form object you use as navigation form page. Each time when you click navigation button, it replaces form object in subform control dynamically. VBA code should work fine if called from inside the form object used as page.